# Is an executable portable between different Nixos hosts which reference different nixpkg commits?

Tags: postgresql, dynamic-linking, nixos, nix

I'm trying to get an executable to work by just copying it directly from one Nixos host to another. It works/executes on only one of the hosts.

On old host (where it works):

```
[root@XenonKiloCranberry:~/blog]# ldd app
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fffd68fb000)
    libm.so.6 => /nix/store/7gx4kiv5m0i7d7qkixq2cwzbr10lvxwc-glibc-2.27/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f591bf32000)
    libpq.so.5 => /nix/store/sf3jq8d81gx6fmxsi0mhagpgsgpnxf6m-postgresql-9.6.12-lib/lib/libpq.so.5 (0x00007f591bd03000)
```

On new host it's not finding the shared library:

```
[root@XenonKiloCranberry:~/blog]# ldd /root/blog/app
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007fff6cb89000)
    libm.so.6 => /nix/store/681354n3k44r8z90m35hm8945vsp95h1-glibc-2.27/lib/libm.so.6 (0x00007f927e00f000)
    libpq.so.5 => not found
```

---

I do see a `libpq.so` file in the postgresql-lib directory on the new host though:

```
[root@XenonKiloCranberry:~/blog]# ll /nix/store/1m0kd7v8yvf5vdmd2jm16w4aal234114-postgresql-9.6.13-lib/lib/libpq.so
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 12 Jan  1  1970 /nix/store/1m0kd7v8yvf5vdmd2jm16w4aal234114-postgresql-9.6.13-lib/lib/libpq.so -> libpq.so.5.9
```

```
[root@XenonKiloCranberry:~/blog]# ll /nix/var/nix/profiles/system/sw/lib/libpq.so.5
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 80 Jan  1  1970 /nix/var/nix/profiles/system/sw/lib/libpq.so.5 -> /nix/store/1m0kd7v8yvf5vdmd2jm16w4aal234114-postgresql-9.6.13-lib/lib/libpq.so.5
```

I've got the `[glibc gmp5 postgresql postgresql.lib zlib.dev zlib.out]` packages installed in my `environment.systemPackages`.

Comment: Did you add the directory where `libpq.so.5` is located to the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` and start a new shell session?

Comment: Are you able to compile the executable from source, or is it only available in binary form?

Comment: I have the source to recompile yes, I would hope that it would be portable none the less as long as the shared libraries are present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Packages built by Nix usually rely on `DT_RUNPATH` entry in ELF files to locate shared libraries. You can use for example `nix run -f . patchelf -c patchelf --print-rpath app` to view the entries. In your case it will return something like this:

```
/nix/store/7gx4kiv5m0i7d7qkixq2cwzbr10lvxwc-glibc-2.27/lib:/nix/store/sf3jq8d81gx6fmxsi0mhagpgsgpnxf6m-postgresql-9.6.12-lib/lib
```

Since these are absolute paths, you will need to have the relevant paths in Nix store for the libraries to be found.

If you know the `nixpkgs` commit you used to build the program, you can run `nix-build -f https://github.com/NixOS/nixpkgs/archive/${commit}.tar.gz -A postgresql.lib` on the second computer to add the library to the store. But beware that unless you add it to GC root, it can be cleared by a garbage collector.

If you built your program as a Nix expression, it is pretty easy to [export the whole closure](https://nixos.org/nix/manual/#ssec-copy-closure) and import it to another computer.

Comment: Thanks for the info! Not that I have the knowledge to understand what it means. But I think the conclusion is - executable are not necessarily portable if managed 'outside of' the Nix store.

Comment: Yeah. Unless you use static linking, you will need to have the libraries in the paths they are looked for. I tried elaborating on the issue some more.